# В зависимости от порядка параметров URL выводить нужные

Tags: php, запрос, url

Есть сайт, на котором необходимо вывести

`<link rel='canonical' href='http://site.ru/?cat=id'>`

Но URL страниц может быть 2 видов:

```
http://site.ru/?cat=id&paged=id

http://site.ru/?paged=id&cat=id
```

id - переменная.
Написал вот такую вещь, но как надо оно всё равно не работает:

```
if (stripos(parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]),'cat') !== false) {

  if (
    ((stripos(current(split('&',parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])['query'],'paged'))) != false))
    &
    ((stripos(next(split('&',parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])['query'],'cat'))) != false))
    ) {
    echo '<link rel="canonical" href="https://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/?'.next(split('&',parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])['query'])).'" />';
    } else {
    echo '<link rel="canonical" href="https://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/?'.current(split('&',parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])['query'])).'" />';
    }
}
```

Где моя ошибка? Возможно есть способ это сделать проще? Придумывать редирект в Apache c `paged=id&cat=id` на `cat=id&paged=id` не хотелось бы.
PHP5

Comment: что-то я про редирект не понял, почему вы в редиректе предлагаете ссылку 2 заменить на ссылку 1? как же вы определите порядок элементов,если он всегда будет один после такого.

Comment: и зачем вы 5 раз вызываете `parse_url`, вам нравится писать очень длинный и непонятный код?

Comment: вам вообще похоже надо просто вывести `<link href="http://site.ru/?cat={$_GET['cat']}">` что ли?

Comment: А зачем вам последовательность определённая? Это как-то влияет на роутинг?

Comment: @teran Вы всё корректно описали и критика очень верная. Спасибо большое за помощь!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if (stripos(parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]),'cat') !== false) {
  echo '<link rel="canonical" href="https://site.com/?cat='.$_GET['cat'].'">';
}
?>
```

спасибо, @teran!

Конечно, можно и без `parse_url`

Comment: нужно, а не можно `if(isset($_GET['cat']))....` ваш код пропустит ссылку `?blablacat=1`, да и смысла в ручном парсинге URL нет никакого

Answer (score 1):

Значения параметров можно брать из массива $_GET, а их порядок определить с помощью функции stripos, в которую передать всю строку запроса. Эта функция не только определяет находится ли подстрока в строке, но и возвращает ее позицию [stripos](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.stripos.php)